# javascript regexp, how detect missing word from regular?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regexp:

```
var patt = /(word)(stmt)(hello)/;
```

and my sample text is :

```
var sample = "wordhello";
```

and cursor is at position index 4;
how can i extract "stmt" from regexp as missing word?

Comment: So you want a non-matching regex to tell you why it didn't match?

Comment: Add a question mark after (stmt) to make it optional. So... /(word)(stmt)?(hello)/ . Note that the "match" (or lack thereof) will be "undefined" and not an empty string.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to test a string on a specific regex, and if it fails, you want to know what part of the regex failed to match? That's beyond the scope of most regex parser, you'll need a regex debugger for that.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your comments and the original regexp pattern, what you want might not actually be a regex, but something like this:

```
function detectMissing(string, set) {
  var offset = 0, missing = [], pos;
  for(var i = 0, l = set.length ; i < l ; i++) {
    pos = string.indexOf(set[i], offset);
    if(pos === -1) {
      missing.push(set[i]);
    } else {
      offset = pos + set[i].length;
    }
  }
  return missing;
}

detectMissing("wordhello", ["word", "stmt", "hello"]); // -> ["stmt"]
```